# How to change the name of database inside mongoid.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Is there any query to change the name of database inside mongoid.yml? I want to make a system where user can give the input of database name by themselves and the database name given by the user should be the name of database. By default mongoid uses the name of project(_development) for the dbs name.

Comment: Is something wrong with the `database` setting? http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration

Comment: No it is working fine. I want to make a module so that user can change the database name for mongo as they want. I want to pass the user input for the name of database to mongoid.yml. Or is there any query to name the database as the user want? for ex,, rails g mongoid:config(here user can give database name?)

Comment: So you want to change the database name while your application is running? Possibly even per-request?

Comment: I mean to say , many users use my project . Each of them have different database name . Is it possible?

Comment: Did you get a solution to your problem? I'm also on the similar lines, though it is not per request or per user but one specific collection is in a different database, so just want to change the name of database for that collection only.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a generator that users needs to run when they setup your application,
[Creating and customizing generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html). See how Mongoid let's you run a generator to generate the `mongoid.yml` http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html#configuration.

So instead of running that generator it could be something like this

`rails g app_name:config`

Comment: I already view these documents. I mean to say how can u make the name of database as u want beside direct editing mogoid.yml